TYPO3 12 ckeditor configuration with multiple site-extensions
I have a TYPO3 12 Installation with multiple Site-Extension, one site-Extension with its own domain and page-tree.
I want to include my custom ckeditor-configuration. You can do it in ext_localconf.php like $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = 'EXT:extensionname/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';
But with several site-Extension it doesn't work, obviously.
What is the best way? Include it in pages.typoscript like
RTE.default.preset = EXT:rechtsinformatik/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml?
But it can't be a yaml-file, right?
Any suggestions?
Thanks

We develop all our projects with a base theme, that includes default configurations and settings for all sites located in this typo3 instance, so changing one thing here, will change everywhere.
On top of this base theme we extend it with the site theme, that contains all of the styles and configuration that should only apply to this site.
So integrating a base theme and require this in your site-extension could solve your problem. Even if it only for the RTE config now, but I guess you have several configs that are redundant and can be extracted to the base theme. Further more updating gets much faster and easier, because your site-extensions will be more compact and contain only files that are related to the site.

Thanks, thats a nice approach, I used pages TSconfig inside site-extension for my current project. So that works for me now, but i keep base them in mind.
